# Compiling with CodeDomProvider doesn't allow new features of C# or VB

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, scripting

I'm compiling some C# and VB code at run time using the CodeDomProvider, CompilerInfo, and CompilerParameters. It works great, and I really like being able to add scripting support to my application, but it only seems to support .NET 2.0 syntax. For example, the var keyword isn't supported in C#, and the If(bool, string, string) expression isn't supported in VB.

How can I tell it to target the 3.5 framework?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, I found a big hint here from [Anders Norås](http://andersnoras.com/blogs/anoras/archive/2008/04/13/codedomproviders-and-compiler-magic.aspx) that there is a constructor for the CSharpCodeProvider constructor that takes some options, including the compiler version. When I checked the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb537926.aspx), I found that it's cleaner to specify the compiler options in the App.config file. Here's an example:

```
<system.codedom>
  <compilers>
    <compiler
      language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript"
      extension=".vb"
      type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, 
        Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, 
        PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
      compilerOptions="/optimize"
      warningLevel="1" >
      <providerOption
        name="CompilerVersion"
        value="v3.5" />
    </compiler>
    <compiler
      language="c#;cs;csharp"
      extension=".cs"
      type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, 
        Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, 
        PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
      compilerOptions="/optimize"
      warningLevel="1" >
      <providerOption
        name="CompilerVersion"
        value="v3.5" />
    </compiler>
  </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

My only disappointment is that now I get two versions of each compiler from CodeDomProvider.GetAllCompilerInfo(). The configuration documentation says that the App.config should override the machine.config settings, but I get both. So far, the App.config is always after the machine.config, so I just let the later ones override the earlier ones. Anybody know how to avoid the duplication?

Comment: Re avoiding duplicates: It looks like there's a contradiction in the MSDN docs: in [<system.codedom> Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6bttwes.aspx) my reading of the Note in the Remarks is config files are not referenced initially for the Framework 2.0, but [<compiler> Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9x69bzw.aspx) says they are, as does __<compilers> Element__.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure where you are going with the app.config's but heres how you can tell it to use 3.5 framework.

```
var csc = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "CompilerVersion", "v3.5" } });
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/lukeh/archive/2007/07/11/c-3-0-and-codedom.aspx